# XNode.DeepEquals considers selfclosing tags and closing tags as different

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to compare two xml documents to equality. One of my document have  self-closing tag and other don't.

```
XNode node = XDocument.Parse("<Root/>");
XNode node2 = XDocument.Parse("<Root></Root>");

bool result = XNode.DeepEquals(node, node2);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[Run it quickly](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Gho3u)

I assume `"<Root/>"` is equivalent to `"<Root></Root>"` however `DeepEquals` says they are not(returns false).

How can I compare these these two documents to be equal?

ps:Not constrained with `XNode`. Solution using `XmlDocument` also welcome.

Comment: You should normalize the XML trees. Eric White blogged about this before: [Equality Semantics of LINQ to XML Trees](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/01/27/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare two documents for equality they should be normalized to some extent.

Eric White made a couple blog posts detailing advanced normalization[1] and simple normalization[2].

To fix the empty tag vs self closing tag the latter article is more relevant.

From the article:

> ```
> static XElement CloneElement(XElement element)
> {
>     return new XElement(element.Name,
>         element.Attributes(),
>         element.Nodes().Select(n =>
>         {
>             XElement e = n as XElement;
>             if (e != null)
>                 return CloneElement(e);
>             return n;
>         })
>     );
> }
> ```

This code will copy an element and its decedents recursively into a normalized form (using the default XElement construction). This includes normalizing empty tags into self closing tags. Comparing the documents will then work as expected.

Consider the following XML:

```
<Foo>
    <Bar/>
    <Root/>
</Foo>
```

and

```
<Foo>
    <Bar></Bar>
    <Root></Root>
</Foo>
```

After using `CloneElement` on each element they will be equal.

```
var node = XElement.Parse("<Foo><Bar/><Root/></Foo>");
var node2 = XElement.Parse("<Foo><Bar></Bar><Root></Root></Foo>");

XElement.DeepEquals(node, node2); // False
XElement.DeepEquals(CloneElement(node), CloneElement(node2)); // True
```

[1]: [Equality Semantics of LINQ to XML Trees](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/01/27/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees/)

[2]: [Empty Elements and Self-Closing Tags](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/07/07/empty-elements-and-self-closing-tags/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure how I missed these posts while I found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/01/27/manually-cloning-linq-to-xml-trees/).